# Product multiselect attribute not saving all the values

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

I have custom multiselect product attribute which contains more than 1000 values. I am using "text" for this attribute, still when I select all the values and save product it saves some values but not saving last 40-50 values.

Is there any solution to save all the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the PHP (default) limitation of `max_input_vars`, which defaults to 1000.

Use google, and find out how to increase this value, and your issue shoud be solved.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I completely forgot about php limitation.